# Active area in navigation bar not full height

Tags: css, navigation

I have a responsive website but the navigation bar is giving me problems.

First problem is the active area for clicking the links is not the full height of the nav bar, I need it to go all the way down.

Second problem is that when i switch to a mobile view the Menu is covering the email address and telephone number.

I have the navigation and the top part fixed, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

I have the page on a test address if anyone wants a look - http://www.classic-travel.co.uk/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi Paulie, how do I add show the code I already have?

Comment: Try a *minimal* [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Paulie, thanks for the help, tried jsfiddle but couldn't get it to work, will try somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

First Problem: not the best solution, just a workaround:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
background: yellow;
color: black;
height: 104px; //ADD HEIGHT OF THE ul
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
color: black;
text-transform: none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
height: 100%; //LET li PICK THE HEIGHT OF ul
}
```

If you find a way not to use pixel in height, it would be better.

Second problem is caused by the position:fixed of the header, you remove it, it will not be covered.

```
<header style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 99; top: 0px; "><div class="gridContainer clearfix">

    ....
 </header>
```

In addiction, do not use css inline, put it into a .css file and use `<link>` tag to include in your html file.